# Given a property name, how can I create a delegate to get its value

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

We have some code that given a property name uses reflection to implement a Comparer.

I would like to store a delegate/Func to get the value rather than paying the reflection price each time we need to get a value.

Given a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to write a function that would create a delegate for me

```
Func<T, object> CreateGetFuncFor<T>(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    return (Func<T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>), 
                                                    null, 
                                                    prop.GetGetMethod());
}
```

The following code works fine for the getting the Name

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };

var funcitonToGetName = CreateGetFuncFor<Person>("Name");
Console.WriteLine(funcitonToGetName(person));

var functionToGetAge = CreateGetFuncFor<Person>("Age");
```

but for the Age proerty it throws an ArgumentException with the message "Error binding to target method"

What am I missing?  Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems odd that you know the declaring type at compile-time but not the property type. Anyway...

You'll need an extra step to convert the property value to an `object` so that it matches the `Func<T,object>` delegate's return type. (The extra step isn't strictly necessary for reference-typed properties, but doesn't do any harm.)

```
Func<T, object> CreateGetFuncFor<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var convert = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<T, object>), convert, parameter);

    return (Func<T, object>)lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Oh I agree - but I can't currently change those parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because Age is essentially defined as:

```
public int Age {get; private set;}
```

and a method returning an `int` is not implicitly convertible to a method returning an `object`, whereas `String` is.

try:

```
Func<T, R> CreateGetFuncFor<T, R>(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (Func<T, R>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, R>), 
                                                    null, 
                                                    prop.GetGetMethod());
}
```

and then

```
var functionToGetAge = CreateGetFuncFor<Person, int>("Age");
```

Comment: Unfortunately in the code where I want to use this I don't know what type the propery is in advance.

Comment: what are you going to do with Age if you don't know the type? can you expand on your use case a little bit.

Comment: eventually the values get used in a call to  System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare